# NoSuchElementException while using Scanner to read input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The following Java method is suppose to accept a string (name of a person) from the user via keyboard, search that name in an array called `name[]` and delete that person's name from the array (by assigning `name[i] = "INVALID"`).

The code tries to accept the input string (the name of the person) using a `Scanner` class object `del_name`, but I am getting a `NoSuchElementException` in the statement

```
s=del_name.next();
```

i.e the 4th statement from the top.

I will be really grateful if someone can give a solution and also explain as to why this code is not working. (Thank You)

```
void Deletee()
{


      Scanner del_name=new Scanner(System.in);

      String s;

      System.out.println("Enter the name to be deleted");

      s=del_name.next(); // causing NoSuchElementException

      int i=0;

   /* find position in which the name occurs using while-loop below */


      while(!s.equalsIgnoreCase(name[i]) && i<count) 

             i++ ;  // increment i to search in next array index



      if(i<count)
      {
          name[i]="INVALID";

          count--;

          System.out.println("Deletion Successful");
      }
      else
      {

          System.out.println("No such person exist");

      }

      del_name.close();


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `.next()` to `.nextLine()`.

```
Scanner del_name=new Scanner(System.in);

String s;

System.out.println("Enter the name to be deleted");

s=del_name.nextLine();
```

Scanner.next() returns whatever the current input is, even if there is none (giving you your error).
Scanner.nextLine() skips past the current line, and returns the skipped portion.

Answer (score 0):

Try with,

```
del_name.nextLine()
```

Using `next()` will only return what comes before a space. `nextLine()` automatically moves the scanner down after returning the current line.

`next():` Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.
`nextLine():` Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you posted does not throw an exception as-is. You might have done something prior to this method call that caused this. As proof, run this code:

```
public class Test {

    static String[] name = new String[] {"AAA", "BBB", "CCC"};

    static void deletee() {

        Scanner delName = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name to be deleted");
        String s = delName.next();

        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            if (name[i].equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                name[i] = "INVALID";
                System.out.println("Deletion Successful");
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
            System.out.println("No such person exist");
        delName.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        deletee();
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
            System.out.print(name[i] + ", ");
    }
}
```

**Notes**:

- Method names should start with lower case.
- Non-final variables should not use underscores, just uppercases where a new word begins.
- I rewrote the searching mechanism for something more intuitive, although there are many more ways to do this.
- Good job on closing the scanner.